# Does gravity affects electromagnetic waves? Or electromagnetism affects gravity?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, gravity, electric-fields

I'm confused about the relationship of electromagnetism and gravity, or are they even related?

It has been said the electromagnetic field produces a gravitational field, and so, there is no gravity if there's no electromagnetism.

I'm new to this topic, I don't understand things without imagining them nor how do they even exist.

Comment: *It has been said the electromagnetic field produces a gravitational field.* It’s too small to be detected except in systems like neutron stars and black holes.

Comment: *so, there is no gravity if there's no electromagnetism* This is flawed logic.

Comment: The OP originally posted this on Worldbuilding, but it was decided that Physics was a better match (so the old question was closed).  On the old question, in a comment, they referred to https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2211379718314128#:~:text=In%20general%20relativity%2C%20it%20is,20%5D%2C%20%5B21%5D as the source of this question.

Comment: Both. Electromagnetic field energy gravitates just as much as e.g. strong force field energy. If that wasn't the case, then the equivalence principle wouldn't hold. We are not aware of any violations as of now.

Answer (score 1):

In Newtonian physics, electromagnetism and gravity are distinct entities with no connection.  However, in general relativity, there's a bit of a connection to be had.  In all physics, mass is associated with gravity.  In simple Newtonian physics, the mass of a system is simply the sum of the mass of its particles.  [In relativity, mass works a bit different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity).  The quantity that matters there is the [energy-momentum tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_tensor).  It includes not only traditional mass (sometimes called "rest mass" in relativity), but also energy such as that stored in fields.  Any field.  Electromagnetism is such a field, so any system which has electromagnetic fields present also has [some mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#The_mass_of_composite_systems):

> The rest mass of a composite system is not the sum of the rest masses of the parts, unless all the parts are at rest. The total mass of a composite system includes the kinetic energy and **field energy** in the system.

(emphasis mine)

Now it is this mass which is associated with gravity.  So electromagnetic fields, which increase the rest mass of the composite system, produce gravity.

From your question:

> It has been said the electromagnetic field produces a gravitational field, and so, there is no gravity if there's no electromagnetism.

This is not accurate.  It's backwards.  If there is electromagnetism, there must be gravity (because there is energy in the fields, thus mass, thus gravity).  However, the opposite is not true.  There's plenty of ways to have gravity without electromagnetism.  Neutral particles generate gravity.

Answer (score 0):

Sources of gravity: energy or matter.
So EM waves can be the source of gravity but it's not the only source that can produce gravity.

Gravity affecting EM waves: EM waves red shifted or blue shifted when it is coming from low gravity to High gravity region or High gravity to low gravity region. This effect is called Gravitational red/blue shift.